# C++17/20 Parallel Algorithms: Unsynchronized accesses to object

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, language-lawyer, c++20

Reading the latest C++20 draft at [[algorithms.parallel.exec]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-2) I found a paragraph which was not there in C++17:

> If an object is modified by an element access function, the algorithm will perform no other unsynchronized accesses to that object. The modifying element access functions are those which are specified as modifying the object. [ *Note*: For example, `swap`, `++`, `--`, `@=`, and assignments modify the object. For the assignment and `@=` operators, only the left argument is modified. — *end note* ]

What is exactly guaranteed by this? Why was it added?

For instance, does this guarantee that a "parallel" algorithm won't increment an iterator twice during the entire execution of the algorithm? (or, if it does, it will be in a synchronized/sequenced fashion)?

Comment: Doesn't http://wg21.link/lwg2932 help?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer It seems like that's it! Thanks! If you or anyone else wants to answer a bit more in detail, it is great too.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Please don't answer in comments.  Post an answer with a bit of detail so we can upvote it :)

Comment: @L.F. I feel lazy to write any details. Feel free to answer.